# Как грамотно передать объект одного класса в другой класс

Tags: php

Как грамотно передать объект одного класса в другой класс, чтобы работать с этим объектом внутри другого класса?

Через аргументы?
Глобальные переменные?
или еще есть варианты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так делаю.

```
class obj {
  public static function a() {
    echo 1;
  }
}

class obj1 {
  function a() {
    obj::a();
  }
}

$obj1 = new obj1;
$obj1->a(); // 1
```

---

Еще так можно.

```
class obj {
  function n() {
    return 123;
  }
}

class obj1 extends obj {
  function b() {
    return $this->n();
  }
}

$obj1 = new obj1;
echo $obj1->n() . '<br />';
echo $obj1->a();
```

Результат:

> 123
>
> 123

**UPD:**

```
class Mysql {
  function insert($user) {
    return $user;
  }
}

class User {
  function User($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  function Add($user) {
    return $this->db->insert($user);
  }
}

$db = new Mysql();
$user = new User($db);
echo $user->Add('Васек');
```

Или

```
class Mysql {
  public static function insert($user) {
    return $user;
  }
}

class User {
  function Add($user) {
    return Mysql::insert($user);
  }
}

$user = new User();
echo $user->Add('Васек');
```

А еще и вот так можно.

```
class Engine {
    public static $db = '';
}

class Mysql {
  function __construct() {
    engine::$db = $this;
  }
  function insert($user) {
    return $user;
  }
}

class User extends Engine {
  function Add($user) {
    return parent::$db->insert($user);
  }
}

$db = new Mysql();
$user = new User();
echo $user->Add('Васек');
```

Во общем есть миллионы алых роз.

Comment: А если такая ситуация:

    $db = new Mysql($params);
    $user = new User();
    $user->Add("Вася");

в классе User надо использовать $db, чтобы добавить в базу юзвера. При этом, чтобы $db обявлялся один раз, а не каждый раз, когда пытаюсь добавить юзвера.

Comment: Обновил пост, ответ там.

Comment: если один раз на запуск скрипта  - то используем класс singleton

Answer (score 2):

Если вы планируете изменять исходный объект, то передавать его следует по ссылке (внешне отличий нет). Если планируете с ним работать, не сохраняя изменения, то передавать следует копию исходного объекта.